# printing data column wise using grep or awk

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files say `(file1.dat, file2.dat)`

```
file1.dat contains a line similar to
     STR       KAPPA2=0 RMAXS=4.2 NDIMIN=0 NOCALC=F IALPHA=0
file2.dat contains 
     class Fe   convergency of s-channel=   0.347E-04
     class Sr   convergency of s-channel=   0.289E-04
     class Bi   convergency of s-channel=   0.111E-04
     class Pt   convergency of s-channel=   0.900E-04
```

I want to get the values of `RMAXS (4.2)` and `convergency` and then store these
values in a file `(say plot)`,  `column wise`

```
4.2    0.347E-04
4.2    0.289E-04
4.2    0.111E-04
4.2    0.900E-04
```

I can get the individual value (using `grep` and `awk`) but don't know how to store them in 
above format.

```
Also is there a way to print the shell variables like `$HOME` or
`$PWD` as the third column in the file (plot).
```

Comment: What's the key to link records between files?

Comment: @fedorqui: Apparently this isn't a `join` question.  I would assume `file1.dat` and `file2.dat` are the outputs from a single experiment, and that the overall process will be to run a series of experiments, overwriting the same files and extracting the values from each run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple Awk solution.

```
awk -v h="$HOME" '# From file1.dat, read RMAXS value into r
    NR==FNR { if (sub(/.*RMAXS=/,"")) { sub(/ .*/,""); r = $0; } next }
    # From file2.dat, print final field along with r and h
    /convergency of s-channel=/ { print r, $NF, h }' file1.dat file2.dat >plot
```

The `-v var=value` option allows you to assign arbitrary variables from the command line.  Here, we use it to set `h` to the value of the environment variable `HOME`.

The `NR` variable keeps track of the line number and the `FNR` variable keeps track of the line number within the current file.  So `NR==FNR` when you are processing the first file.  If `RMAXS=` is found, the value is extracted and assigned to `r`.  If there are other lines in the file, they are simply skipped.

If we fall through, we are in the second file; if a line matches the `convergency` regex, we print the final field (`NF` counts the number of fields on the line, by default whitespace-separated) along with the values of the two variables.

A naive attempt would use one Awk script to extract the value of `RMAXS` from the first file and feed that as a variable to a second Awk script.  The `NR==FNR` trick allows us to do it all in one process, and IMHO improves readability (once you understand how it works!)

Answer (score 0):

based on the information you gave so far. what you need is `echo and grep` see this example:

we have two file: f1 and f2:

```
kent$  head f*
==> f1 <==
STR       KAPPA2=0 RMAXS=4.2 NDIMIN=0 NOCALC=F IALPHA=0

==> f2 <==
 class Sr   convergency of s-channel=   0.347E-04
```

now do this line:

```
kent$  echo "$(grep -Po '(?<=RMAXS=)[^\s]*' f1)\t$(grep -Po 'channel=\s*\K[^\s]*' f2)\t$PWD" > f3
```

check the newly generated file, `f3`:

```
kent$  cat f3
4.2    0.347E-04    /tmp/test
```

the 3 columns are `<tab>` separated. you could change it to other separator in the `echo` line.

Comment: I am not getting the correct output, its printing `4.2\t0.347E-04\t/home/surender/garbage`

Comment: The `\t` represents a tab; replace it with a space or a literal tab character if your `echo` doesn't support backslash escapes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that each RMAXS value in file1 corresponds with the respective sequential convergency value in file2, etc:

```
paste <(grep -oP 'RMAXS=\K\S+' file1.dat) \
      <(grep -oP 'convergency[^=]+=\s*\K\S+' file2.dat) | 
sed "$(printf 's#$#\t%s#' "$HOME")"
```

The `<(cmd arg ...)` syntax is called [process substitiution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). You can treat a pipeline of commands like a file that other commands can read from or write to. Here are links to documentation to [`paste`](http://man.cx/paste), [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html), [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), [perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [`printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf)

Comment: this is exactly what I want, but can you explain the syntax a bit more or point to some references. I guess a backslash is missing after the pipe.

Comment: No backslash is required after a pipe or `&&` or `||`

Comment: Please specify all your requirements in the question, not scatted in comments.